# Google Sheet - put 3 dynamic columns (number of raw changes) one after the other to create a list

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google script file that extracts 3 different tables from the internet.
As the tables get updated, the number of rows of these table changes. For example day one Table 1 has 3 rows and day 2 it has 4, while day 3 it may be 0 (number of column does not change but is not important).

Is there a way to create a column that contains all the first column elements of Table1, then first column elements of Table 2 and first column elements of Table 3?

I individuated this formula to get always the max row for each column:
`ROW(index(B:B,COUNTA(B:B),1))`

But I do not know how to put the three columns in one. Do I necessarily need a script?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

you need to construct the array like:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(A1:C3,  {"","",""}); 
 IFERROR(A6:C6,  {"","",""});
 IFERROR(A9:C10, {"","",""})}, "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

where you change the actual ranges for your import fx

note the use of `"","",""` for 3 columns

[image]